# Left Join in Flask SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I want to do a left-join in flask-sql alchemy.

```sql
SELECT * FROM CARLOGS
LEFT JOIN vehicles ON vehicles.id = CARLOGS.vehicle_id;
```

Now In Flask-sqlalchemy, I have tried the simple join, which works

```py
CarLogs.query.join(Vehicle, CarLogs.vehicle_id == Vehicle.id)
```

But, if I want to do a left join, I can not find any option on the documentation of flask-sqlalchemy.

```py
db.session.query(CarLogs, Vehicle).leftjoin(CarLogs.vehicle_id == Vehicle.id)) # inspired by a so answer, gives error
```

or

```
CarLogs.query.leftjoin(Vehicle, CarLogs.vehicle_id == Vehicle.id) # Gives error
```

Error message:

```
AttributeError: 'BaseQuery' object has no attribute 'leftjoin'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try join with isouter parameter

```
CarLogs.query.join(Vehicle, CarLogs.vehicle_id == Vehicle.id, isouter=True)
```

Comment: It works, but it does not give all the columns that the original query(which I mentioned in start) gives. It only gives the CarLogs column, if I print the type of the returned object, it is `<class 'db.CarLogs'>`.

Comment: after join add

.add_columns(CarLogs.column1, CarLogs.column2, Vehicle.column1, Vehicle.columsn2)

Comment: THank you so much. Cant find this information anywhere in the documentation.